# influxDB HTTPConnectionPool Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-requests, influxdb

I have system that includes BLE sensors and raspberry pi. In raspi my python(v2.7) scripts get datas from BLE and create influxDB if there is not and append datas to it. influxDB is on raspberry. I added start command for python script on rc.local. For the first time it starts and everything is good. After 6~10 hr (alots of data saved on db) when i restart raspberry it could not start script becase it does not reach database when system boot. Error is:

```
error initializing influxDB output interface HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.1.0.66', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=SHOW+DATABASES&db=db_omrons (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x75e60670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))Exit
```

But when I connect with SSH and start script with manually on command line after this error it starts perfectly. I dont know reason exactly but my guess is that is about starting time of influxDB not enough fast for my python script control on boot. My tries are(not successed):

- adding sleep command at rc.local before start the python script
- changing urlopen function parameter (in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpooly.py) retries=retries to retries=False and retries=1`return self.urlopen(
              method, redirect_location, body, headers,
              retries=retries , redirect=redirect,
              assert_same_host=assert_same_host,
              timeout=timeout, pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
              release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)`
- changing host name 'localhost' to direct raspberry IP adress '10.1.0.66' (as you can see over error)
- waiting network connection on boot (not relevant but just for try)

successed but not usable method to solve is:

- remove indluxDB totaly with purge and reinstall it

Comment: Could you provide your code? We can test it and figure out where is going wrong.

Comment: Of course. it is an open source and the github is: https://github.com/OmronMicroDevices/envsensor-observer-py and main starting script is envsensor_observer.py

Comment: You have to debug. Figure out at which particular point you've got this connection refusal (and don't forget to record the time point too!) - that's first step to get the clue of what's going on. Then, check the InfluxDB startup logs, take the the point in time you previously recorded, and match to what was going on at that moment.